# Display Port monitor not detected Ubuntu 14.04 - VGA ok - Intel GC

Tags: 14.04, drivers, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics

I know this question has been asked already, but nothing I found on the internet solved my problem.

I have 2 monitors connected to a docking station. I have an integrated Intel Graphic Card

Monitor 1: VGA

Monitor 2: Display Port (DP)

On windows the monitor is working fine. 
If I start my Ubuntu session with the DP monitor branched I get the error: 
*The system is running in low-graphics mode*

I tried to follow the solution to this question but it didn't work:
[How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

The one over display port is not detected, even if when I branch/debranch the cable the monitor wakes up but then it says NO SIGNAL and it goes to sleep.

This is the output of my `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     40.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      59.9*+
   1920x1080      60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This is the output of my `uname -a`

```
Linux USERNAME 4.4.0-96-generic #119~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 08:40:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the output of my `lspci | grep VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the Intel display driver. If you are willing to take the risk you should uninstall the Intel display driver. The system will fall back to a modesetting generic driver. Your monitors will now work but graphics quality will be worse.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I found a solution which did not mean to reinstall my drivers.

Answer (score 2):

I found a possible solution to my problem.

I just went here: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_-_Trusty_Tahr

And followed the instructions to do the Ubuntu **LTS enablement (also called HWE or Hardware Enablement) stack**.

---

**For Ubuntu 14.04 (my version)** I just did

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
```

---

**For Ubuntu 16.04** you should do

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

---

I just did that command, rebooted and the monitor were detected without any problem. This is my highly suggested solution. Read more about it on the link above.

I hope this will help someone else with the same problem

Comment: this also worked for me. just to add, I have twp display ports and 1 vga. when I started, I placed it on displayport1 then displayport2. then I did the command. it wasn't working. and then I used the other display port then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with the Displayport-VGA adapter. So I used DisplayPort-HDMI & HDMI-VGA adapters instead. Now all 2 external monitors show up.